# How do you remove a queue binding from RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, py-amqplib

I am using RabbitMQ to route messages to interested subscribers by topic. Each subscriber has a queue, and I bind the queue to the topics they are interested in.  I would like to allow the user to remove an item from their topic list.

In my setup, that would require "unbinding" the bound topic from that user's queue.

I am using pyamqplib, and I am not seeing a way to do this via the channel object.  Is their a way to remove previously bound routing keys from a queue?

Answer (score 5):

```
public void unsubscribe(String queuename, String topic) throws IOException
{
   ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
   factory.setHost(MQ_HOST);
   factory.setPort(MQ_PORT);

   Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
   Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
   try
   {
      channel.exchangeDeclarePassive("Channel name");
      channel.queueUnbind(queuename, "Channel name", topic);
   }
   finally
   {
      handleClose(connection, channel);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Working in Python?

Looks to me like pika 0.13 has an [unbind method](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/channel.html?highlight=bind#pika.channel.Channel.queue_unbind):

```
queue_unbind(queue, exchange=None, routing_key=None, arguments=None, callback=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this

[How to selectively delete messages from an AMQP (RabbitMQ) queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434763)

solve your problem?